# "Deu ruim" é gíria usada em todo o Brasil?

Tags: origem, regionalismo, gíria

Com o significado de "alguma coisa deu errado" ou "algo terminou mal", ouço "deu ruim" falado entre alguns adolescentes, e até adultos, principalmente aqueles pertencentes às classes menos favorecidas do Rio de Janeiro. Exemplo: "deu ruim, algum X9 deve ter avisado à polícia e a gente teve que ralar peito".

Minha pergunta é, "deu ruim":

- É gíria originária dos subúrbios cariocas?
- É usada em outros estados do Brasil?

Não acredito que seja usada em Portugal, exceto talvez por alguns brasileiros.

Comment: Me lembro de ver apenas, pela TV, nos mesmos contextos que você menciona.

Comment: Aqui em SP, sim, se usa, mas tende bastante a ser usado comicamente. Ao menos aqui, apenas vi pessoas mais jovens. O único momento no qual não seria cômico seria nessa situação em que alguém "pegou", mas, mesmo assim, eu ainda sentiria um ar cômico ou uma tentativa, para mim engraçada, de "falar tipo bandido". Interessante que também se fala “dar bom”, como “vou jogar na loteria. Espero que dê bom!”, este já não vejo como cômico.

Comment: Uso em SP, mas não sabia que era originário de vocabulário carioca. Primeira vez que ouvi foi por um aluno em de escola técnica por volta de 2012, não recordo origem da pessoa. Desde então ouço até que bastante não necessariamente ser carioca. https://guiltyfornothing.blogspot.com/2012/ (na verdade é retirado do Globo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maioria das pesquisas que realizei apontam para regionalismo carioca, mas não encontrei nada substancial que indique a origem de subúrbio.

Pesquisando dentro da ferramenta [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=BR&q=%22deu%20ruim%22) o termo **deu ruim**:

1. Aparecem algumas entradas em 2008, mas tem uma pequena constante em 2011 para frente.
2. Entre 2015 e 2016 aparece a música [*Cuidado com a pinga*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlb1u5h3JiY), aumentando assim a incidência de busca pelo termo, segue trecho da música:

> Deu ruim, bebeu pinga deu ruim
>
> O *trem é bão* no começo
>
> Te vira do avesso
>
> Mas no outro dia a ressaca é maldita

*Trem é bão*: Regionalismo de Minas Gerais.

3. Na mesma época programa de TV *Tattoo Fixers* adaptado título para *Deu ruim na tattoo*.
4. Regiões com mais procura no Brasil até hoje por ordem de mais resultados: **Rio de Janeiro**, Minas Gerais, São Paulo, Paraná, Santa Catarina e Rio Grande do Sul.
5. Portugal não tem quantidade suficiente para gerar informações.

Moro em São Paulo, como comentei ouvi pela primeira vez em 2012 em uma escola técnica, não sei a origem da pessoa, então as pessoas que ali frequentam tem seus 15 a 19 anos. Desde então é uma gíria usada e ouvida sem restrição de idade.

Acho que o termo é um substituto para *merda* e consegue denotar a mesma intensidade de negatividade sem usar uma palavra de baixo calão. Parte curiosa é a [proporção do "deu merda" e "deu ruim" no Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=BR&q=deu%20ruim,deu%20merda).

O uso de certas palavras mesmo que de forma errada, pode ser um meio de desvio da filtragem de ofensas e palavrões em redes sociais.

Comment: Eu morava no interior de SP e ouvi pela primeira vez mais ou menos na mesma época quando me mudei para o Rio a trabalho, mas por pessoas de várias idades (desde jovens de 16-18 anos até adultos na faixa dos 30-40)

Answer (score 3):

Acho que certas faixas etárias utilizam mais essa expressão, mas ela é bem conhecida sim em todo o brasil! Moro em Recife, conheço pessoas do Sul, SP, Rio e várias do nordeste e todas utilizam. Em videos na internet ouço sempre também. Basicamente, eu ouço sempre em todo o lugar e o tempo inteiro!

Comment: Interessante, bom ter esse dado do nordeste.

Answer (score 1):

Já viajei a vários lugares do Brasil. Seu uso não é muito comum, mas certamente não causaria estranheza na maior parte das regiões do Brasil.